# C# using ArrayList from another class

Tags: c#, object, arraylist, addition

I have one class Racun.cs

```
public class Racun
{
    private string _nazivKupca;
    public string NazivKupca
    {
        get
        {
            return _nazivKupca;
        }
        set
        {
            _nazivKupca = value;
        }
    }

    private string _djelatnik;
    public string Djelatnik
    {
        get
        {
            return _djelatnik;
        }
        set
        {
            _djelatnik = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime Datum
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    private string _brojRacuna;
    public string BrojRacuna
    {
        get
        {
            return _brojRacuna;
        }
        set
        {
            _brojRacuna = value;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList _listaStavaka = new ArrayList(); 
    public ArrayList ListaStavaka
    {
        get { return _listaStavaka; } 
    }
```

And now I am trying to save objects into this `ArrayList ListaStavaka` from my main program.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    Racun racun = new Racun();
    Console.Write("Kupac: ");
    racun.NazivKupca = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Djelatnik: ");
    racun.Djelatnik = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Broj računa: ");
    racun.BrojRacuna = Console.ReadLine();

    char unos = 'd';

        do
        {
            Stavka stavka = new Stavka();
            Console.Write("Naziv proizvoda: ");
            stavka.NazivProizvoda = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Kolicina:  ");
            stavka.Kolicina = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Jedinicna mjera:  ");
            stavka.JedinicnaMjera = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Cjena bez pdv-a: ");
            stavka.Cijena = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            ListaStavaka.Add(stavka);

            Console.WriteLine("Zelite li unjeti novu stavku (D/N): ");
            unos = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

        } while (Char.ToUpper(unos) == 'D');
```

I get error message

> The name 'ListaStavaka' does not exist in the current context.

So my question is when I have `ArrayList` in another class, how do I add objects into this `ArrayList` in my main program? What do I need to do in main program for this to work ?

Please, I searched this problem, and everybody are suggesting that `List<T>` should be used instead, but I really need to use `ArrayList`. Thank you.

EDIT:

Ok, so I managed to solve this problem, and now I have another problem:

I tried this:

```
 foreach (var item in racun.ListaStavaka)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("| {0}.{1}, {2} {3}, {4} kn/{5} = {6} kn", i, item.NazivProizvoda, item.Kolicina, item.JedinicnaMjera, item.Cijena, item.JedinicnaMjera, item.UkupnaCijena());
            i++;
            ukupno = ukupno + item.UkupnaCijena();
        }
```

But I get errors in every property i wrote in this WriteLine row ... "'object' does not contain a definition for 'NazivProizvoda' and no extension method 'NazivProizvoda' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" ... I don't get it, because this properties are properties form object "Stavka" i saved into this ArrayList with "racun.ListaStavaka()" ... So what did I do wrong ?

Comment: I edited my code. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I see now if I put racun. into ListaStavaka.Add() to get racun.ListaStavaka.Add("test") it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where your actual `ListaStavaka` is declared.

Your code demonstrates an instance of it as one of the properties of your `Racun` class, so if you have an instance of this class, you should be able to access it as expected :

```
// Create an instance of your Racun object so that you can access it's properties
var racun = new Racun();
// After instantiating an object, you can access its public properties 
// as expected
racun.ListStavaka.Add("test");
```

Without an object, you would otherwise need to create an instance of an [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) and simply call it `ListaStavaka` to use it :

```
// Create an ArrayList on it's own
var ListaStavaka = new ArrayList();
// Add to the array list
ListaStavaka.Add("test");
```

**Update Regarding Second Part of Question**

When displaying your elements from the ArrayList, which are `Stavka` objects, you might want to indicate that within your loop so that .NET knows what they are (otherwise it assumes they are generic `object` types) :

```
foreach (Stavka item in racun.ListaStavaka)
{
     // Access your properties using item.NazivProizvoda, etc. here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me, but now I have another problem/question :(

Comment: I edited original question, you can see my problem at the bottom of the question.